# Как кроссбраузерно (IE10+) получить блок такой формы?

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно получить блок такой формы? Вариант с бордерами не подходит, в блоке фоном изображение..

Comment: может использовать png изображение?

Comment: изображение внутри блока нужно будет перемещать..

Comment: вариант с clip-path - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d4nxjnyg/, но у него поддержка браузерами хромает http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: да, про этот способ я знаю, но поддержка, к сожалению, никакая..

Comment: `:before` и `:after` элементы с `transform: rotate(45deg)` попробуйте

Comment: Тогда придется резать картинку на две части, хотелось бы этого избежать, так как такой элемент не один..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял, но должно работать:

```css
div {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG);
  position: relative;
  border: 1em solid silver;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

div:before {
  left: 0;
  border-width: 64px 0 64px 64px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent silver;
}

div:after {
  right: 0;
  border-width: 64px 64px 64px 0;
  border-color: transparent silver transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```